# Divisibility between the degree of two extension fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I am working on this problem:

> Let $K$ be an extension field of a field $F$, and let $\alpha \in K$ be algebraic over $F$, with minimal polynomial $p(x)$. Let $\beta \in F(\alpha)$ be algebraic over $F$, with minimal polynomial $q(x)$. Prove that $\deg(q)\mid \deg(p)$.

I'm stuck at starting this problem so I would appreciate some hints for it.

Comment: $F \subseteq F(\beta) \subseteq F(\alpha)$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$\dim_F F(\alpha)=\dim_{F(\beta)} F(\alpha)\cdot \dim_F F(\beta).$$

Comment: do you mean this:
$[F(\alpha):F] = [F(\alpha):F(\beta)] [F(\beta):F]$

Comment: Yes, it's just another notation.

Comment: From the problem, I have $[F(\alpha):F] $ = deg $q$, and $  [F(\alpha):F(\beta)]  = 1$, hence $[F(\beta):F]$ = deg $q$. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: Not quite: How do you know $F(\alpha)=F(\beta)$?

Comment: From $[F(\alpha):F] = [F(\alpha):F(\beta)] [F(\beta):F]$ one gets deg $p =  [F(\alpha):F(\beta)]$ deg $q$.